Webi formula for extracting date from text field
I have got the following web intelligence formula (Business Objects) which works for most of my data to extract a date from a text field;
=If(Pos([Note]; “R”) > 0 And Length(Substr([Note]; Pos([Note]; “R”) + 1; 6)) 
=6;FormatDate(ToDate(Substr([Note]; Pos([Note]; “R”) + 1; 6);“ddMMyy”);“yyyy/MM/dd”);
“Invalid Date”
)

However the text field I am extracting from can contain other “R” values, and the formula does not account for this. I would like to update this formula to account for values beginning with “R” that are followed only by numeric values. Is there a way of doing this?
Below is some sample data that I am extracting from, its the values 180723 I want to extract after the 'R' in this example.
The ‘RDDMMYY’ is normally at the start of the text field but it can be also in the middle which is causing me the issue.
“Please add to Reading list BMS999 crn 1234 Req R180723 Oversize QP34.5.M27 2023 put previous ed on standard loan and withdraw 10th ed (2005) from stock”
Thanks
Blowers

Will it always be "Req RDDMMYY"?

The text can vary in the note field, so the only constant is "RDDMMYY". Sometimes the note contains "Rec" or "Req" but not directly beside the DDMMYY value I want to extract.
